# How to use erode and dilate function in opencv?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm trying to eliminate the thing around the number with erode and dilate process. I tryed but nothing happened. I changed the values just for see if would change something, but again, nothing has changed. The image continues like in the link above. What about this parameters... I read the documentation but don't quite understand (as you can see, I was guessing in the function). What am I doing wrong?

the image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzUNc6BOkYrNeVhYUk1oQjFSQTQ/edit?usp=sharing

the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    Mat im_gray;
    Mat img_bw;
    Mat img_final;

    Mat im_rgb  = imread("cam.jpg");
    cvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);


    adaptiveThreshold(im_gray, img_bw, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 105, 1); 


    dilate(img_bw, img_final, 0, Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);


    imwrite("cam_final.jpg", img_final);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, let's start from the documentation http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20dilate%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29 give me a moment...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [official docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate), the third argument should be the kernel (or structuring element). You are currently passing 0:

```
dilate(img_bw, img_final, 0, Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
```

Try rewriting it this way:

```
dilate(img_bw, img_final, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
```

In this case, a default 3x3 kernel will be used.

Comment: @Anne That constructs an empty `cv::Mat`. According to the docs, "if `element=Mat()` , a 3 x 3 rectangular structuring element is used."

Answer (score 1):

Kernel is basically a matrix. This is multiplied or overlapped on the input matrix(image) to produce the desired output modified(in this case dilated) matrix(image).

Try changing the parameters of `Mat()` in 
`dilate(img_bw, img_final, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);`
you're basically changing the number of pixels (height and width) of the kernel, which will change the dilation effect on the original pic.

So in the parameters of `dilate` you use `Mat()` instead of a number as already stated by esenti.